# How to select a table with no ID or class

Tags: c#, watin

**Clarification** - I'm using [Watin](http://watin.org/) to automate the browser. It's a Watin Table object I need to create, not a javascript object.

I'm using watin to extract data from a web app. I need to create a watin `Table` but the table in the html has neither an ID nor a class.

It is nested in another table though, inside a div which has an id of `detailsDiv`.

```
<div id="detailsDiv">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <table> <!-- This is the table I need to get to-->

            </table>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can create an object from that table without the id or class?

Comment: can you share the HTML and isn't it possible to add an id or name?

Comment: I dont own the application. Posting html.

Comment: Please add some HTML code. And why not add an ID? I think that would be better. Else just get all elements by the tagname TABLE and get the first element.

Comment: Then you have to use index number.  Use GetElementsByTagName and then get table by the index in response.

Comment: @jdweng any suggestion on how GetElementsByTagName would be used with watin?

Comment: See following webpage.  A Waitin Table can be access by index number. http://watin.org/documentation/element-class-mapping-table/

Comment: @jdweng rows can, tables cannot as far as I get from that documentation.

Comment: Seems like the documentation is terrible, but I'd try [Find.BySelector](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/WatiN/WatiN.Core/Find/M/BySelector) Or something like [this idea to use jQuery](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/11/11/fast-er-css-selector-based-element-lookups-in-watin-via-jquery/)  I've never used Watin...

Comment: @DanielCook U might be onto something. Checking now

Comment: don't add solution in the question, add an answer.

Comment: The webpage sow following : Ie.Table(tableId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I've managed to come up with. May help someone else in the future:

```
Div detailsDiv = ie.Div("detailsDiv");

TableCollection tableColl = detailsDiv.Tables;
Table featuresTable = tableColl[1];
```